# org-mode wrongly take * in a math equation as mark of bold font

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I wrote the following line in org-mode, which contains two equations.

```
$(Z^{*}_{m}, \cdot m)$  $(Z^{*}_{m}, \cdot m)$
```

But the org-mode didn't identify them as equations. Instead, it highlight the part between the two `*`s, i.e. `}_{m}, \cdot m)$  $(Z^{`, making this part bold. Is this a bug of org-mode or my own mistake?

Update: if the braces enclosing the "*" are removed (like below) org-mode can parse it correctly. Strange...

```
$(Z^*_{m}, \cdot m)$  $(Z^*_{m}, \cdot m)$
```

Comment: What version of org-mode are you running? Works fine for me (6.21b).

Comment: I can replicate with the org-mode head. I would suggest you report this on the mailing list. Since the devs hang around there, this kind of a problem gets addressed there much faster.